# How can I implement Pagination in SAP SUP?

Tags: sybase, sup

Lets say I have few thousands of records in some MBO. I do not want to download all these records to my device during synchronization. I want to implement "paging" let's say with 100 records per page. So each new synchronization caused by user entered a new page, must add to my mobile divices database new 100 records.

Is these scenario possible with SAP SUP? May be, I can specify Personalization Parameters with not just equal ("="), but  "<", ">" or sort of that signs? May I specify not just a value, but a range for  Personalization Parameter?

Pagination is common mechanic for many WEB resources, sites, app and so on.
Can anyone share best practices in solving such kind of problems in SUP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested I've found the solution. There is a "Customized download data" checkbox on the "Synchronization" tab for every MBOs properties in Unwired Workspace. It allows us to write custom SQL Queries to CDB and inject Personalization Params into those queries.

Hope it will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

What SUP offers you is the partioning of data per user, If say in your case you have 1000 records, you can apply filters called syncronization parametrs and personalization parameters which will allow you to filter the data comming to your device. The syncronization  of mobile device database with the SUP server database happens initially or as per users request, So you cannot acheive paging kind of stuff.